# Issue in Loading Shipping Price in Order Summary at Checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout

I am working on a Magento2 project and its behaviors is little bit annoyed.

Please see the attached image and see that shipping price is not loading right side `Order Summary` area while its fine at bottom of the page.[image]

Further, I would like to share that we have installed following shipping extensions:

- Amasty_ShippingTableRates
- Magento_Multishipping
- Magento_OfflineShipping
- Magento_Shipping

Please guide in this regard.

Comment: Have you got any solution for the issue? I am having the same issue.

Comment: No any solution. While it causes due to JS files not properly deployed. So need to re-deploy every time.